# Infragistics UltraLabel disable tooltip

Tags: c#, tooltip, infragistics

I just placed a UltraLabel into a form and run it. When I hover the mouse over the label a tooltip is shown by default. If I place a normal .net label control it doesnt show any tooltip. So seems is something set by default in UltraLabel control and I can't find a way to get rid of the tooltip.

Does anyone know how to disable or remove it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I wish to ask you what properties do you have changed from their default value. (Using the designer or through code)

Comment: Nothing Steve. Just dragged and placed on the form.

Comment: Just found how to... I set AutoEllipsis = false :) Thanks

Comment: I see, not a WinForms label then.....

Answer (score 0):

Both the inbox Label and the UltraLabel show the tooltip when the text of the label exceeds the size of the label and AutoEllipsis is set to true.  If the size of the label is increased such that the text can all be displayed you will no longer see the tooltip.  You can change the behavior by setting AutoEllipsis to false, but you should note that the text of your label will then be cut off and your users will not be able to see all of the text unless you also increase the size of the label.

You can also set AutoSize to true if you want the label to size to its contents to prevent the text from being clipped.